# Python3 - using pandas to group rows, where two colums contain values in forward or reverse order: v1,v2 or v2,v1

Tags: excel, pandas, python-3.6

I'm fairly new to python and pandas, but I've written code that reads an excel workbook, and groups rows based on the values contained in two columns.

So where Col_1=A and Col_2=B, **or** Col_1=B and Col_2=A, both would be assigned a GroupID=1.

[sample spreadsheet data, with rows color coded for ease of visibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEO1n.png)
I've manged to get this working, but I wanted to know if there's a more simpler/efficient/cleaner/less-clunky way to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

# get column values into a list
col_group = df.groupby(['Header_2','Header_3'])
original_list = list(col_group.groups)

# parse list to remove 'reverse-duplicates'
new_list = []
for a,b in original_list:
    if (b,a) not in new_list:
        new_list.append((a,b))

# iterate through each row in the DataFrame
# check to see if values in the new_list[] exist, in forward or reverse
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for a,b in new_list:
        # if the values exist in forward direction
        if (a in df.loc[index, "Header_2"]) and (b in df.loc[index,"Header_3"]):
            # GroupID value given, where value is index in the new_list[]
            df.loc[index,"GroupID"] = new_list.index((a,b))+1
        # else check if value exists in the reverse direction
        if (b in df.loc[index, "Header_2"]) and (a in df.loc[index,"Header_3"]):
            df.loc[index,"GroupID"] = new_list.index((a,b))+1

# Finally write the DataFrame to a new spreadsheet
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
```

I know of the *pandas.groupby([columnA, columnB])* option, but I couldn't figure a way to create groups that contained both (v1, v2) **and** (v2,v1).

Answer (score 0):

A boolean mask should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
mask = ((df['Header_2'] == 'A') & (df['Header_3'] == 'B') |
        (df['Header_2'] == 'B') & (df['Header_3'] == 'A'))

# Label each row in the original DataFrame with
# 1 if it matches the specified criteria, and
# 0 if it does not.
# This column can now be used in groupby operations.
df.loc[:, 'match_flag'] = mask.astype(int)

# Get rows that match the criteria
df[mask]
# Get rows that do not match the criteria
df[~mask]
```

**EDIT:** updated answer to address the `groupby` requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

#make the ordering consistent
df["group1"] = df[["Header_2","Header_3"]].max(axis=1)
df["group2"] = df[["Header_2","Header_3"]].min(axis=1)

#group them together
df = df.sort_values(by=["group1","group2"])
```

If you need to deal with more than two columns, I can write up a more general way to do this.